# How to fix following error in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, substitution

I have one bash script file which is working well in Ubuntu 16.04, but it's not working since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10.

```
#!/bin/bash

a="1"
name="a"
value=${!name}
echo "value=" $value   # "value=1"

name="some string"
value=${!name}         # bad substitution error
```

In Ubuntu 16.04, value=${!name} does not occur "bad substitution error" and it assigns empty value to "value".
But in Ubuntu 18.04, it says "bad substitution error" and stops working.
I want it to work as in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please post bash versions on ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Do they differ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 GNU bash version 4.3.48(1)-release
Ubuntu 18.10 GNU bash version 4.4.19(1)-release

Comment: It keeps working for me with Ubuntu 18.04 (With bash 4.4.20)

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated the issue with [rextester](https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler) with bash 4.3.46 and [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) with bash 4.4.12.

I see, like, three options:

1. Downgrade your bash version. This looks like a bug in older bash version that was fixed.
2. Ignore and redirect the error message to null.

```
value="";                              # first assign empty value
{ value=${!name}; } 2>/dev/null ||:    # this doesn't do anything if !name is invalid
```

3. You can write a single if. And write proper code and never dereference variable with invalid variable name in it.

```
isValidVarName() {
    echo "$1" | grep -q '^[_[:alpha:]][_[:alpha:][:digit:]]*$' && return || return 1
}
if isValidVarName "$name"; then
    value=${!name}
else
    value=""
fi
```

Comment: How can I downgrade bash version? It's dangerous to downgrade bash version and seldom used.